# How to handle ENTER button press on JQuery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog, defaultbutton

I am using JQuery Dialog Box.

I have got below code where I am opening my Dialog Box.

```
  $('#MyLogin').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 450,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                title: $('.LoginpopupHeaderText').text(),
                close: function(event, ui) {showSelect();}
            });
```

When Dialog box is open, there is login button in it, which validate the username and password field in it using click event. Please see below code sample.

```
    //Login Button Clicked
    $('#loginButton').click(function()
    {   
            //Code goes here
        });
```

My Login Button is an Image not a button.

Now I want to catch "**Enter**" button press only when my Login Dialog is open as well as after catching the "Enter" button it should call my "**loginButton**" click event, so that it will behave like we have clicked the loginbutton on open dialog box.

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if the button is visible

```
$('body').keyup(function(e) {
   if ($('#MyLogin').is(':visible') && e.which == 13) {
      //stuff
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Yads, can't we use "open: function()" of dialog box and then give focus to my login button which is image, if yes can you please suggest how can I do it as I am not able to put focus on it.

Comment: @MKS, it may be possible, give it a go. However, when the user clicks anywhere (like a text field) then your proposed solution breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Register a JS function on your "**onLoad**" event of the div  **MyLogin** e.g.

```
     <div id="MyLogin" onload="javascript:return checkKeyPress();" />
```

In **checkKeyPress** function check if the keyCode is 13 the submit the form e.g. pseudocode

```
    event.preventDefault() ;
    if (keyCode == 13 )
          frm.submit();

    return false;
```

Remember that **event.preventDefault**  and **return false** line is must, otherwise the  **KeyPress event** will propagate to main form/page. Hope this will help.